# DuplicateFreeQ VS UnsameQ

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

What is the exact  difference between
`DuplicateFreeQ @ arr`  and  `UnsameQ @@ arr` ?
I checked on many examples and found no difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation for [`DuplicateFreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DuplicateFreeQ.html) says

> `DuplicateFreeQ[list]` is essentially equivalent to `SameQ[list, DeleteDuplicates[list]]`.

So I don't expect there to be any difference with the `Apply[UnsameQ]`.

However, the two important usage distinctions are:

#### 1. Performance

```
arr = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000}];
    
DuplicateFreeQ@arr // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.00469843, True} *)
    
UnsameQ @@ arr // RepeatedTiming
(* {12.2089, True} *)

SameQ[arr, DeleteDuplicates[arr]] // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.0053803, True} *)
```

#### 2. Custom test function

`DuplicateFreeQ` accepts the second argunent to serve as a test function.